# Issue with GestureListener

Tags: android

I am having a gesture listener attached to a view and I have onSingleTap Event handled. 
It handles it properly if I tap anywhere in the view. But say if the View is having any subview and if I am tapping the subview the event does not get triggered.

Is there a way to pass this touch from child to parent? And also the children contains BUTTONS. so if the press is on a child button it should not pass the touch to parent. Otherwise it must pass it to parent. Anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the Activity's `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` in order to handle the dispatching yourself.
A good handling would be to first check if it triggers the gesture in your view and if not just call super.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent);
The one thing you have to care about while doing this is to keep the gestures coherent with the rest of the platform.

Comment: but it will trigger the touch no matter I touch anywhere in the view right? I have buttons inside the view which when touched should not trigger the view touch

Comment: Absolutely. As the name suggest, it is up to you to dispatch the Events. Again, a good way to do this is to check if the event should go to your view to be handled by your gestures and if not call the super method to let the framework dispatch the Event itself.